# Sample from a Bayesian network in pomegranate

Tags: python, machine-learning, python-3.5, bayesian-networks, pomegranate

I constructed a Bayesian network using `from_samples()` in pomegranate. I'm able to get maximally likely predictions from the model using `model.predict()`. I wanted to know if there is a way to sample from this Bayesian network conditionally(or unconditionally)? i.e. is there a get random samples from the network and not the maximally likely predictions?

I looked at `model.sample()`, but it was raising `NotImplementedError`.

Also if this is not possible to do using `pomegranate`, what other libraries are great for Bayesian networks in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `model.sample()` [should have been implemente](https://github.com/jmschrei/pomegranate/blob/master/pomegranate/bayes.pyx#L135)d by now if I see the commit history correctly.

You can have a look at [PyMC](https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/) which supports distribution mixtures as well.
However, I dont know any other toolbox with a similar factory method like `from_samples()` in pomogranate.

Comment: the linked commit is for the BayesModel class not the BayesianNetwork class about which the OP is inquiring. see here: https://github.com/jmschrei/pomegranate/blob/master/pomegranate/BayesianNetwork.pyx

Answer (score 3):

Just to elucidate the above answers with a concrete example, so that it will be helpful for someone, let's start with the following simple dataset (with 4 variables and 5 data points):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,0,0,1,0], 'B':[0,0,1,0,0], 'C':[1,1,0,0,1], 'D':[0,1,0,1,1]})
df.head()

#   A   B   C   D
#0  0   0   1   0
#1  0   0   1   1
#2  0   1   0   0
#3  1   0   0   1
#4  0   0   1   1
```

Now let's learn the Bayesian Network structure from the above data using the `'exact'` algorithm with `pomegranate` (uses DP/A* to learn the optimal BN structure), using the following code snippet

```
import numpy as np
from pomegranate.bayesian_network import *
model = BayesianNetwork.from_samples(df.to_numpy(), state_names=df.columns.values, algorithm='exact')
# model.plot()
```

The BN structure that is learn is shown in the next figure along with the corresponding CPTs

[image]

As can be seen from the above figure, it explains the data exactly. We can compute the log-likelihood of the data with the model as follows:

```
np.sum(model.log_probability(df.to_numpy()))
# -7.253364813857112
```

Once the BN structure is learnt, we can sample from the BN as follows:

```
model.sample()  
# array([[0, 1, 0, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

As a side note, if we use `algorithm='chow-liu'` instead (which finds a tree-like structure with fast approximation), we shall obtain the following BN:

[image]

The log-likelihood of the data this time is

```
np.sum(model.log_probability(df.to_numpy()))
# -8.386987635761297
```

which indicates the algorithm `exact` finds better estimate.

Comment: How did you print CPTs in the figures above ? model.plot() shows only nodes/edges without CPTs.

Answer (score 0):

One way to sample from a 'baked' BayesianNetwork is using the predict_proba method. predict_proba returns a list of distributions corresponding to each node for which information was not provided, conditioned on the information that was provided.

e.g. :

```
bn = BayesianNetwork.from_samples(X)
proba = bn.predict_proba({"1":1,"2":0}) # proba will be an array of dists
samples = np.empty_like(proba)
for i in np.arange(proba.shape[0]):
    for j in np.arange(proba.shape[1]):
        if hasattr(proba[i][j],'sample'):
            samples[i,j] = proba[i][j].sample(10000).mean() #sample and aggregate however you want
        else:
            samples[i,j] = proba[i][j]
pd.Series(samples,index=X.columns) #convert samples to a pandas.Series with column labels as index
```