# Bayesian network in Python: both construction and sampling

Tags: python, sampling, bayesian-networks, pomegranate

For a project, I need to create synthetic categorical data containing specific dependencies between the attributes. This can be done by sampling from a pre-defined Bayesian Network. After some exploration on the internet, I found that `Pomegranate` is a good package for Bayesian Networks, however - as far as I'm concerned - it seems unpossible to sample from such a pre-defined Bayesian Network. As an example, `model.sample()` raises a `NotImplementedError` (despite [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51035303/sample-from-a-bayesian-network-in-pomegranate) solution says so).

Does anyone know if there exists a library which provides a good interface for the construction and sampling of/from a Bayesian network?

Comment: Are you willing to: 1) switch languages or 2) implement sampling yourself?

Comment: Please note that questions asking for recommendations are usually off-topic here (see the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). The first part is okay though. I don't know the answer, maybe the Pomegranate package isn't that mature so far.

Comment: @kutschkem I am looking for a library that provides a good interface for **defining** a Bayesian Network from which I can then sample to obtain a synthetic data-set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that PyAgrum (https://agrum.gitlab.io/pages/pyagrum.html) does the job. It can both be used to create a Bayesian Network via the `BayesNet()` class and to sample from such a network by using the `.drawSamples()` method from the a `BNDatabaseGenerator()` [class](https://pyagrum.readthedocs.io/en/0.16.3/BNToolsGener.html).

Answer (score 5):

Using pyAgrum, you just have to :

```py
#import pyAgrum
import pyAgrum as gum

# create a BN
bn=gum.fastBN("A->B[3]<-C{yes|No}->D")
# specify some CPTs (randomly filled by fastBN)
bn.cpt("A").fillWith([0.3,0.7])

# and then generate a database
gum.generateCSV(bn,"sample.csv",1000,with_labels=True,random_order=False) 
# which returns the LL(database)
```

[the code in a notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgMNf.png)

See http://webia.lip6.fr/~phw/aGrUM/docs/last/notebooks/ for more notebooks using  pyAgrum

*Disclaimer*: I am one of the authors of pyAgrum :-)

Comment: Yes I found out about this. Pretty cool that you're responding because I yesterday put a reference to pyAgrum (containing your name) in my paper, as I'm using PyAgrum for many things, but mostly for inference in BN's with soft evidence!

Answer (score 4):

Another option is [pgmpy](https://github.com/pgmpy/pgmpy) which is a Python library for learning (structure and parameter) and inference (statistical and causal) in Bayesian Networks.

You can generate forward and rejection samples as a Pandas dataframe or numpy recarray.

The following code generates 20 forward samples from the Bayesian network "diff -> grade <- intel" as recarray.

```
from pgmpy.models.BayesianModel import BayesianModel
from pgmpy.factors.discrete import TabularCPD
from pgmpy.sampling import BayesianModelSampling

student = BayesianModel([('diff', 'grade'), ('intel', 'grade')])

cpd_d = TabularCPD('diff', 2, [[0.6], [0.4]])
cpd_i = TabularCPD('intel', 2, [[0.7], [0.3]])
cpd_g = TabularCPD('grade', 3, [[0.3, 0.05, 0.9, 0.5], [0.4, 0.25, 0.08, 0.3], [0.3, 0.7, 0.02, 0.2]], ['intel', 'diff'], [2, 2])

student.add_cpds(cpd_d, cpd_i, cpd_g)
inference = BayesianModelSampling(student)
df_samples = inference.forward_sample(size=20, return_type='recarray')

print(df_samples)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is Bayespy (https://www.bayespy.org/index.html).
You build the network using nodes. 
And on every node, you can call `random()` which essentially samples from its distribution: https://www.bayespy.org/dev_api/generated/generated/bayespy.inference.vmp.nodes.stochastic.Stochastic.random.html#bayespy.inference.vmp.nodes.stochastic.Stochastic.random

Answer (score 1):

I was also searching for a library in python to work with bayesian networks learning, sampling, inference and I found [bnlearn](https://erdogant.github.io/bnlearn/pages/html/index.html). I tried a couple of examples and it worked. It is possible to import several existing repositories or any .bif type. As per this library,

> Sampling of data is based on forward sampling from joint distribution of the Bayesian network. In order to do that, it requires as input a DAG connected with CPDs. It is also possible to create a DAG manually (see create DAG section) or load an existing one